# path dinâmico fora do contexto em servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, jsp, servlet

Para pegar o path dinâmico dentro do projeto é fácil, basta executar o código :

```
String path = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
```

Aqui é retornado:

```
/home/pedro-pazello/development/servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/wtpwebapps/img_uploader/
```

*img_uploader* é o nome do projeto. Porém eu preciso pegar esse caminho fora do projeto. Eu preciso que o caminho seja:

```
/home/pedro-pazello/development/servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/wtpwebapps/imagens/
```

Alguém tem ideia de como posso pegar esse path?

Comment: Você pode tentar passar `"../imagens"` para o `getRealPath`, mas acredito que isso é um indício de que sua configuração não está muito acertada. Você pode colocar em mais detalhes porque você quer acessar uma pasta fora do projeto?

Comment: Você quer pegar o path dentro do nível web ou fora? Pergunto isso porque eu tinha que fazer os 2 em um projeto, e dava esse problema.

Comment: Por que você não salva esse path no banco de dados e depois só busca fazendo um select? [=

Comment: Eu precisso salvar os arquivos fora do projeto,porque sempre que um servidor tomcat reinicia,ele faz re-deploy das aplicações,dai todos os arquivos que eu salvei durante o tempo que a aplicação ficou online vão embora,porque a aplicação retorna para o padrão do war...posso até salvar o path no banco de dados de boas,porém queria pegar ele de forma dinamica...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

**OPÇÃO 1**

```
String path = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("../imagens");
File f = new File(path);
String imagensHome = f.getCanonicalPath();
```

Você pode então criar um Servlet para atender as requisições em `/img_uploader` e entregar as imagens a partir de :

```
File imagensRoot = new File(imagensHome);
```

Você deverá dedicar uma atenção especial ao Mime Type das imagens na hora de entregar ao cliente atribuindo o Content Type adequado.

**OPÇÃO 2**

Vale apenas se seu servidor estiver rodando Tomcat 7+ no Linux, UNIX ou MAC OS X

1. Crie um link simbólico usando `ln -s img_uploader ../imagens`
2. Crie um arquivo `context.xml` como abaixo:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context allowLinking="true">
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
   </Context>
   ```

Este arquivo informa ao Tomcat via atributo `allowLinking="true"` que ele pode acessar links simbólicos e entregar conteúdo ao cliente a partir de `../imagens`.

OBS: nesta solução um script de Deploy deve recriar este link simbólico descrito acima no caso dele ser removido.

Comment: Primeira opção parece ser interessante,apesar de,eu estar pensando em salvar o path em um arquvio xml ou banco,e puxar esse path quando necessário,e caso eu precisasse mudar ele,bastava mudar esse xml ou registro do banco,de qualquer forma vou testar a primera opção depois